# Style input range before and after to append another style class

Tags: html, css

I am using input range in my jsf page. I need append the another style class before and after the input range because before the input I need to show ui-icon-plusthick(plus icon) and after to show ui-icon-minus(minus icon).

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="100" max="500" step="10" class="slider" />
```

Now I need .slider:before to add .ui-icon-plusthick and .slider:after to need append ui-icon-minus. Is this Possible?

Answer (score 2):

Input element does not have `:before` or `:after` because it can't have inner content.

Use some wrapper for that

```css
.ui-icon-plusthick:before {
  content: '+';
  display: inline-block;
}
.ui-icon-minus:before {
  content: '-';
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-wrapper {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <span class="ui-icon-minus"></span><input id="slider1" type="range" min="100" max="500" step="10" class="slider" /><span class="ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

input can't have ::before or ::after elements. Try wrapping a  around the input and do the span:after

Or just use an img element after, as this will work too.